# bash prompt: show current directory at end of line

Tags: command-line, bash, prompt

How to make my bash prompt display something at the **end** of the line (with the cursor positioned as usual at the beginning of the same line)?  Specifically I want to display an abbreviated single character prompt such as `$` or `>` after which I can type my command. But I want to be able to see the current working directory at the end of the line, where it is not "in my face".

I don't care what happens when I type a really long command. It can overwrite the current working directory or whatever else my prompt displays there.

Alternately I don't mind if the prompt causes the current working directory to show at the top right or top left, or bottom right/left of the screen.  I just don't want it in my face at all times but I want it to be visible.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to set PS1 to something that prints the current path at the end of the prompt line:

```
PS1='\[$(for ((i=1; i < COLUMNS - ${#PWD} - 3; ++i)) ; do printf " " ; done ; printf "$PWD")\]'
```

But it has several problems I wasn't able to solve:

1. The path disappears when you press <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
2. Despite the fact the whole expression is enclosed in zero-width marker `\[...\]`, once you print also the `$` or `>`, the cursor moves to the far right.

I've seen people using `PROMPT_COMMAND=pwd` instead to show the path, but it reduces the number of lines containing your commands in the terminal.

Another option is to configure your terminal or screen/tmux to display the path somewhere. For example, the following works in xterm:

```
PS1='\[\e[m\e]0;\W\a\]$ '
```

The sequence `\e[m\e]0;...\a` sets the title of the window. In screen, it's  `"\033k\033\0134\033kTITLE\033\0134"`.

Comment: genius!  that's *almost* perfect for my usage (too bad about not being able to add a `$` or `>`); i don't mind it disappearing with a backspace since it's optional information anyway.  I will accept after a while just to let all answers come in. Thank you :-)